# como sacar el promedio de una consulta en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo esta consulta en laravel orm

```
     $linea = CeldaLinea::select('nro_linea','celda_prod')
                                        ->whereBetween('fecha',[$fechaInicial, $fechaFinal])
                                        ->groupBy('nro_linea','celda_prod')
                                        ->get();
```

como hago para que por cada resultado de nro_linea sacar el promedio del campo celda_prod y traerme ambos resultados en un array o collect

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una *raw expression* (consultas SQL en estado puro) para seleccionar el agregado [AVG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg) (promedio).
Hay un [buen ejemplo](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#raw-expressions) en la doc de laravel. Adaptado a tu consulta seria algo asi:

```php
$linea = CeldaLinea::select('nro_linea', DB::raw('AVG(celda_prod) as celda_prod_promedio')
    ->whereBetween('fecha',[$fechaInicial, $fechaFinal])
    ->groupBy('nro_linea')
    ->get();
```

Explicado linea por linea:

1. Seleccionas la columna por la cual quieres agrupar y el agregado AVG.
2. La clausula where para filtrar las filas.
3. Agrupas por la columna que te interesa (la que esta en el select).
4. Ejecutas la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Otra forma de hacerlo sin `DB::raw` es utilizando [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-map).

Ejemplo:

```
$linea = CeldaLinea::select('nro_linea', 'celda_prod')
    ->whereBetween('fecha', ['2023-10-01', '2023-10-03'])
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('nro_linea')
    ->map(function ($groupedItems) {
        return $groupedItems->avg('celda_prod');
    });
```

Utilizamos el método `map` para calcular el promedio de 'celda_prod' para cada grupo (Es decir, cada 'nro_linea') utilizando el método `avg`.